# Jquery loan calculator giving me NaN variables

Tags: jquery, calculator, nan

I'm using inputs for "rate" "amount" "months" and "payment."

When a user clicks calculate, it should be pulling the values of "rate" "amount" and "months" and calculating the payment. The values at start are:

```
$('#loanAmount').val("$" + loanAmount); 
$('#apr').val(apr - 1.6 + "%"); 
$('#months').val(months);
```

I'm trying to remove any of the non-number characters and do the math, but they are all returning "NaN" in my first alert below with everything I've tried.

```
 $('#submit').on('click', function () {

        var rawLoanAmount1 = ($('#loanAmount').val());
        var rawApr1 = ($('#apr').val());
        var rawMonths1 = ($('#months').val());

        var rawLoanAmount2 = rawLoanAmount1.replace(/\D/g,'');
        var rawApr2 = rawApr1.replace(/\D/g,'');
        var rawMonths2 = rawMonths1.replace(/\D/g,'');

        var loanAmount = parseInt($(rawLoanAmount2).val());
        var apr = parseFloat($(rawApr2).val());
        var months = parseInt($(rawMonths2).val());


        alert("apr =" + apr + " loanAmount =" + loanAmount + " months =" + months);

        var newApr = apr / 1200;


        var firstStep = 1 + newApr;
        var secondStep = Math.pow(firstStep, months);
        var thirdStep = newApr * secondStep;

        var top = thirdStep;


        var firstStepB = 1 + newApr;
        var secondStepB = Math.pow(firstStepB, months);
        var thirdStepB = secondStepB - 1;

        var bottom = thirdStepB;


        var firstStepComp = top / bottom;
        var secondStepComp = loanAmount * firstStepComp;

        var compAnswer = secondStepComp;

        var compAnswerRounded = Math.round(compAnswer);

        var tal = parseInt($(compAnswerRounded).val());

        $('#payment').val(tal);

        return false;

    })
```

Comment: use `parseInt` before getting any integer values..

Comment: your problem is you are trying to do a selector on your values: `$(rawLoanAmount2).val()` so unless that `rawLoanAmount2` is a selector of a valid element, `.val()` will be undefined which when you `parseInt` or `parseFloat`, will become a `NaN`, just change it to `parseInt(rawLoanAmount2)`, `parseFloat(rawApr2)`, etc...